# How to show a custom post type on a static wordpress front page within the post loop?

Tags: wordpress, loops

My wordpress theme has a static front page and NO blog page enabled. On the static front page there is a loop which shows all the (regular) posts.

I have generated successfuly a CPT named 'buch'.

I now have managed to show "buch" in the loop on category- and archive-pages.
Unfortunately my main aim still is and always has been to show 'buch' and 'post' within the loop on the static front page. I have so far searched the web, this forum and also intensely studied the code (hoping to find the loop in the templates).

Would anyone of you have some short solution maybe for the functions-file that´s rock-solid? Or an idea where to look for the loop in first place, with console, if even possible?

Comment: Take a look at this question on WPSE: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242473/how-to-put-custom-post-types-on-front-page. If you have a static front page, you'll most likely need to modify the shortcodes in the content of that page, the functions that control those shortcodes, or the template tags in that page's template PHP file - depending on how it was set up.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes, this is exactely the post I have been coming back to again and again these days! The static page I refer to in my theme handles the posts by function, I am 99% sure about it. Problem is: I am looking all over and cannot find it. I am a real noob, so I looked around the template files for loop-like structures. I thought there would maybe be a way see and locate functions like css-classes in console?!?! I guess I was wrong?

Comment: You can't locate PHP loop structures in the console because PHP is an interpreted language that gets interpreted as bytecode, processed by the server, and sends back HTML to the browser. You'll need to use FTP and search through your theme (or possibly plugins) files for the code you're looking for.

Comment: Thx for clearing this up, I see! That´s what I have done two times, but I will give it a third try nevertheless. I might have overseen it completely! Cheers and thank you!